# Filter original array based on a property value of an object in an array on the original parent object

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have an array of PowerShell objects called `$releases`. A release contains an ID, Name, and an **optional** array of objects for projects associated with the release. Each project has an ID and Name property. An example is shown below.

```
id                  : 1
name                : Release 5
associated_projects : {@{id=50; name=Project 1}}

id                  : 2
name                : Release 6
associated_projects : {@{id=51; name=Project 2}}

id                  : 3
name                : Release 7
```

I want to filter the result so that only those releases that have associated projects with a specific associated project id are returned. For instance, if my associated project id were 50 I would return release 1 from the example above.

My initial approach would be to simply iterate through the releases with a nested for-each to look for the associated project's id. When found, add the releases to another array and return the result. However, it seems there may be a more appropriate way to handle this in PowerShell using Where-Object. Yet, my attempt at filter this collection based on a  property value of an object in an array on the original parent object has failed.

Is there a better way to filter this that would be more idiomatic to PowerShell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
PS> $releases | ?{ $_.associated_projects -ne $null }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
associated_projects            {id, name}
name                           Release 5
id                             1
associated_projects            {id, name}
name                           Release 6
id                             2
```

This filters out the objects whose `associated_projects` key is not `$null`.

Comment: I also want to be able to include those releases where the release has an associated project with a specific id, e.g., associated_project.id -eq 50 would return release 1

Comment: Like this? `$releases | ?{ $_.associated_projects.id -eq 50 }`

Answer (score 2):

```
$releases | Where-Object { $_.associated_projects.id -eq 50 }
```